# How to use this keyword for store variable

Tags: codeigniter

How to use this keyword in codeigniter to store values. Beacuse i use same value multiple time in the same page.

So if the this keyword is help to solve this problem.

```
function1() {
    $value = '123456';
    $assign1 = $value;
    .....
}

function2() {
    $value = '123456';
    $assign2 = $value;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We store value using **this** keyword inside the **_construct()** function to over come this problem.

The sample code,

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();
    $this->value = '123456';
}
function1() {
    $assign1 = $this->value;
    .....
}

function2() {
    $assign2 = $this->value;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can declare it as a global variable and use with `$this`, you can do this in a constructor or above constructor, both will work nice

```
class MyClass extends CI_Controller {
      var $value = '123456';//global variable
      function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         //$this->value = '123456';
      }
      function1() {
         $assign1 = $this->value;
         .....
      }

      function2() {
         $assign2 = $this->value;
         .....
      }
}
```